# using the same pronoun twice in the same sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I was going over [this](https://bitbucket.org/toters/customer-ios/pull-requests/10/ics-5/commits) article and I found the structure of this sentence interesting:

> **Mr Trump** will never forgive those whom, like Mitch McConnell, the Senate leader, **he** judges to have failed him by acknowledging Mr Biden’s election victory. Having begun to move against him, they should finish the job.

Is this proper english? It would be good news to me because I always find it awkward when I interrupt my sentence with a long fyi statement, then proceed to continue the original thought without somehow being able to reconnect or reset the original statement (I'm not even sure what that style is called).

So here are my questions:

1. What is this type of writing called (the structure etc)?
2. Can I see more examples of this sentence structure where the pronoun is written twice?

Comment: Where's the second instance of "he" you're referring to? Note that "he" can't be dropped (I'm referring to the grammar, not the politics, of course).

Comment: Yes, it's "proper English."

Comment: @Lawrence I didn't mean to say that the sentence used "he" twice, it's more the fact the sentence first used "Mr Trump" then used "he" to refer to Mr Trump again in the same sentence. I found that structure very unusual but also very clear and useful. I would like to use the same structure in my own sentences but first I would like to understand the structure better.

Comment: It might help to simplify the sentence to *Mr. Trump will never forgive those whom he judges to have failed him.* Probably, your confusion arises from the combination of two non-essential phrases (*like Mitch McConnell* and *the senate leader*) being side by side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's simplify the sentence so that you can see that both "Mr Trump" and "he" ***must*** be there:

> [Mr Trump will never forgive those]**(A)** [whom (...) he judges to have failed him]**(B)**.

You have (A), the main clause whose subject is ***Mr Trump*** and then you have (B), the relative clause modifying the pronoun ***those***, whose subject is ***he***.

You cannot say "I know those whom love", a subordinate clause needs a subject. You need to say: "I know those whom ***I*** love".

Comment: Very nicely said. I really appreciate this.